# how can i store parse object directly in NsuserDefault?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfobject

```
PFQuery *Location = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Location"];
[Location findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {      
  NSLog(@"%@", [objects objectAtIndex:0]);             
}];
```

How can i store this object in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: in here u get the objects/results

Comment: yes i get the object in array.

Comment: show the answer what u get, I modify your ?

Comment: Dai , naan unoda ? modify panirukaen ena answer varuthunu solu pa

Comment: i cant understand this. please elaborate it .
and i have not enough reputation For Edit Question
Please Solve my Problem.. i m so troble.

Comment: Check my updated answer ma

Comment: in updated code insert data in nsuserdefult Successfully .but in retrive data app crash.
error like
+[PFObject parseClassName]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x104b8be38

Comment: then my answer is fine show your crash report and print the result what u saved in userdefault

Comment: PFQuery *Overview = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Overview"];
    [Overview findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
     {

Comment: Apparry_Overview=objects.copy;
         if (objects.count==0)
         {
             // do nothing
         }
         else

Comment: {
             for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                 
                 NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object];
                 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"yourkey"];
                 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
             }
         }
         
         NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"yourkey"];
         NSArray *retrieveArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

         NSLog(@"-->%@",retrieveArray);

Comment: show my  last three comment this my code.

Comment: whats your retrieveArray console report\

Comment: its crash app.error like +[PFObject parseClassName]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x104b8be38

Comment: sry bro in here we try alternate idea just wait

Comment: please give me vote for this question bro.

Comment: I aleady removed your negative mark - now u get the  answer or not

Comment: but give me vote for my answer so i can go to chat and solve my solution bro.

Answer (score 0):

For storing custom objects u need to add these two methods in your m file of custom object class

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    //Encode the properties of the object
    [encoder encodeObject:self.contact_fname forKey:@"contact_fname"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.contact_lname forKey:@"contact_lname"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.contact_image forKey:@"contact_image"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.contact_phone_number forKey:@"contact_phone_number"];

}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if ( self != nil )
    {
        //decode the properties
        self.contact_fname = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"contact_fname"];
        self.contact_lname = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"contact_lname"];
        self.contact_image = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"contact_image"];
        self.contact_phone_number = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"contact_phone_number"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

then

```
-(void)writeArrayWithCustomObjToUserDefaults:(NSString *)keyName withArray:(NSMutableArray *)myArray
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];
    [defaults setObject:data forKey:keyName];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

-(NSArray *)readArrayWithCustomObjFromUserDefaults:(NSString*)keyName
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:keyName];
    NSArray *myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    [defaults synchronize];
    return myArray;
}
```

use these functions for storing and reading custom object arrays
or u could simply use this library https://github.com/roomorama/RMMapper

Comment: is there a Way to Directly Save Array in nsuserDefault??

Comment: I already use RMMapper But i not solve my Proble.
I will return error like this
'+[PFObject parseClassName]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10f2f7e68'

Comment: <Overview: 0x7ff343450b00, objectId: dHUdDXSi1o, localId: (null)> { Description = "Our mobile app is designed to improve your San Francisco experience, providing information regarding our Hop On - Hop Off bus service and popular unique things our wonderful city has to offer. "; Language = en; Title = Details; }

Answer (score 0):

There is a constraint on what kind of objects can be stored in the `user defaults`, detailed on the [Apple documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:):

> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects. See [What is a Property List](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-54303)? in [Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i).

You will need to convert your array of objects to an array of dictionaries, one of the ways to achieve this is to implement a `toDictionary` method that will take all properties and put them into a dictionary.

You'll also need the reverse method, an `initWithDictionary:` if you'll also want to re-create the objects from the user defaults (you can use the converted dictionaries if you want, though).

Once you have the conversion methods, you can use the [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) methods to store and retrieve the objects.